# Is there an implementation of org.hibernate.envers.Audited in the JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

**Hibernate Envers**
Is there an implementation of org.hibernate.envers.Audited in the JPA?
What is the best way to apply data versioning when using Spring Data JPA technology? What dependencies need to be included? Please share your experience.
How about Spring Data extension to work with Hibernate Envers?

Comment: If you are using Hibernate as a JPA provider you can just use Hiberrnate Envers.

Comment: What dependencies need to be included for Maven?

Comment: Hibernate envers... What else?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hibernate envers**

- Once the Envers-project jar file has been added to the classpath (or depending on Maven), it can be used without further configuration.
- An entity class can be selectively audited using the **@org.hibernate.envers.Audited** annotation on an entity.
  By marking a class with this annotation, hibernate will version all properties, including collections. To exclude a property, you need to mark the class field (collection, relation) with the **@org.hibernate.envers.NotAudited** annotation.
- Hibernate will generate (or look up) additional tables in the database to store archived data for each entity instance annotated with the **@org.hibernate.envers.Audited** annotation.

The change history is stored in the **SOME_ENTITY_AUD** tables corresponding to the **SomeEntity** instances.
A REVINFO table is also created. When the data changes and then commits the transaction, Hibernate will store the new version number with a timestamp in the REVINFO table. The **SOME_ENTITY_AUD** table additionally has two fields 1) *REV << PK >> << FK >>* - a reference to **REVINFO**, 2) The *REVTYPE* column stores the change type: whether a particular entity instance was added, changed or removed during the transaction. [In Java it is represented as enum RevisionType](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-envers/src/main/java/org/hibernate/envers/RevisionType.java)

- 0-ADD
- 1-MOD
- 2-DEL

Envers never deletes version information and archived data; even after calling the remove() method on a SomeEntity instance, its previous version will still be stored in the SOME_ENTITY_AUD table.
Also the SOME_ENTITY_AUD table has a field REVTYPE. It shows what type of operation is.
**GET AUDIT DATA:**

Using the Envers **AuditReader** interface, you can find the version number for each set of changes:

```
AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(em);
```

Search for sets:

```
List<Number> itemRevisions = auditReader.getRevisions(Item.class, ITEM_ID);
```

Getting timestamp:

```
 for (Number itemRevision : itemRevisions) {
       Date itemRevisionTimestamp = auditReader.getRevisionDate(itemRevision);
       // ...
    }
```

Get the version number:

```
Number revisionUpdate = auditReader.getRevisionNumberForDate(TIMESTAMP);
```

Entity lookup:

```
SomeEntity someEntity = auditReader.find(Item.class, ITEM_ID, revisionUpdate);
```

If neither timestamps nor version numbers are known, you can create a query using the **forRevisionsOfEntity()** method and retrieve all entries from the audit log for a particular entity.