# How can I add in my audit table a column with actions that was done (modify, create,delete) using Hibernate Envers?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I know the type of operations are represented like numbers but can I make them appear as string type ("UPDATE / DELETE / INSERT")

I think rev or revtype show what type of operation is ( I tried edit, delete and insert in this order and that s the result )

[This is my product_aud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVYvn.png)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess it's impossible.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/#configuration), the config `org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name` specifies the operation type and defaults to `REVTYPE`. And looking at your screenshot, you have that column with 3 distinct values, which look like enum ordinals

Comment: It is an `enum`: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-envers/src/main/java/org/hibernate/envers/RevisionType.java

Comment: If you really need the string value you could create an insert trigger on the database table that adds this to a separate colunn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change history is stored in the SOME_ENTITY_AUD tables corresponding to the SomeEntity instances. The SOME_ENTITY_AUD table has a field - REVTYPE - Represented by numbers from 0 to 2:

- 0-ADD
- 1-MOD
- 2-DEL

[See more details in the same question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71763753/is-there-an-implementation-of-org-hibernate-envers-audited-in-the-jpa/71765462#71765462)

Comment: Ty, this make sense and I saw MySQL represent enums like INT so I think when or if I want access the data from table will be clearer :)